# Database access error when running azure web app on dev machine

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure, ef-code-first

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2012 that contains an azure project and an MVC web project among others. The web project is using Entity Framework Code First. The database is localdb. If I set the web project as the startup project, it runs fine locally. Code First changes are propagated to the database and the app runs fine when debugging. If I set the azure project as the startup project to run locally under the app fabric, I get the error below when logging into the application and hit the database for the first time. The app runs fine when deployed to azure. I can access the database locally through SQL Server Management Studio. The app can access the database fine when the web app is set as the startup project. I thought it might be database permissions, so I changed the connection string for localdb to not use a trusted connection and created a new login in the local database with sysadmin privileges. Same error.

Here is the connection string:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=[Database Name];User ID=[User Name];Password=[Password];Integrated Security=False; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
```

Here is the error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.

Comment: Can you show your connection string?

Comment: Sorry, meant to include the connection string. I added it to my original post.

Comment: And can you describe how you connect in SSMS to the server instance where you created the new login? I'm betting it's not a localdb connection...

Comment: When I connect locally in SSMS, the server name is set to: (localdb)\v11.0 and I use windows authentication. I can connect to the localdb in SSMS using that new account. I've also set BUILTIN\users to be sysadmin just trying to get it to work. My thinking in doing that was that since it connects fine when the web app is running but not when running under the azure app fabric was that they are running as two different user names behind the scenes.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar error. Looking at the Application event log I could see that I had two different errors repeting. I googled them and found [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/12/09/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-1-user-profile.aspx) that described a solution. Apparently in Windows 7 SP1 you have to edit *applicationHost.config* found in %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\ and change

```
<add name="ASP.NET v4.0" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" />
```

to

```
<add name="ASP.NET v4.0" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated">
<processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="true" />
</add>
```

I did this and it still was not working. I saw that I had Network Services named with GUIDS and I added the same properties to them. After I recycled all Application Pools the problem was solved.

Hope this helps. Perhaps someone with more knowledge can explain the reason behind all this.